# How do you multiply this

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

How can you multiply these ordinal numbers:
$(\omega+1)(\omega+1)(\omega2+2)$

I tried and have gotten to this:
$(\omega^2+1)(\omega2+2)$
Is that the correct way, or did i made a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinal multiplication is distributive in the rightmost element. Therefore

$$(\omega+1)(\omega+1)=(\omega+1)\omega+(\omega+1)=\omega^2+\omega+1$$

Therefore:

\begin{align*}
(\omega+1)(\omega+1)(\omega\cdot2+2) &=(\omega+1)(\omega+1)\omega\cdot2+(\omega+1)(\omega+1)2 \\ &=(\omega+1)(\omega+1)\omega+(\omega+1)(\omega+1)\omega+(\omega+1)(\omega+1)2 \\ &= (\omega^2+\omega+1)\omega+(\omega^2+\omega+1)\omega+(\omega^2+\omega+1)+(\omega^2+\omega+1) \\ &= \omega^3+\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+1+\omega^2+\omega+1 \\ &=\omega^3 \cdot 2+ \omega^2 \cdot 2 + \omega + 1 \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correct. Have you tried to compute the Cantor normal form? If I am not mistaken, it should be $\omega^3 2 + \omega^2 2 + 1$.

edit: my bad, I made the same mistake ($(\omega+1)^2 = \omega^2 +1$) as you. As written above, the correct answer is $\omega^3 2 + \omega^2 2 + \omega + 1$.

Comment: Yes,i made that mistake too, i should be mlre careful with it,and use as much distributivity as i can to ease the graphic or calculating.